# SQL - SAP HANA - Use only first entry in Column table (based on date/time)

Tags: sql, duplicates, hana

I have some tables on SAP HANA and „create column table“ to combine multiple „raw tables“.
In one table, there are duplicate rows, to be more specific, every Information (column) is the same but the date/time is not.So the source System has this weird habit to create one entry, several times (which is wrong). I do not have the possibility to manipulate data in the source System.
The table looks something like:

- Table name: Testsubject_status
- Column: Status....info....Timestamp
- Test me...............bla.......05.01.2017 05:05:00
- Test me...............bla......01.01.2017 11:15:00
- Test him………..blub…..01.01.2017 11:17:00
- Test her  ………..blab.....01.01.2017 11:25:00
- Test me    ………..bla.......01.01.2017 11:35:00
- Test it………......blue......01.01.2017 12:15:00
- Test me     ………..bla.......07.01.2017 12:15:00

All duplicates after the first entry (date/time whise) should be not considered in the newly created table.

- Table name: Testsubject_status_NEW
- Column: Status....info....Timestamp
- Test me...............bla......01.01.2017 11:15:00
- Test him………..blub…..01.01.2017 11:17:00
- Test her  ………..blab.....01.01.2017 11:25:00
- Test it………......blue......01.01.2017 12:15:00

This problem does appear multiple times, not only with Test me.

Is the solution something like:
Select

- xxx AS "tri"
- yyy AS "tre"
- zzz AS "tru"
- Case when Testsubject_status.Status Count > 1 Then "take first entry"
- From ...
- Where …

???

I am glad for every help or advice.

Comment: You might want to use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to generate a more readable and [formatted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) representation of your sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the description it should be sufficient to aggregate for the maximum date:

```
SELECT tri, tre, tru,
           max(timestamp) 
FROM
    ....
```

That works if the „de-duplication“ indeed should happen based on **all** remaining columns except `timestamp`.

Comment: great...now i got it... I used max(CAST(CAST(table1.date AS DATE) || ' ' || CAST(table.time AS TIME) AS TIMESTAMP)) ...the missing Thing for me was the "Group by" Statement in the WHERE part of my Code... I needed to include all columns from my table and now… works like needed! Thanks!